# categories of custom post type shows in CMS but not in the frontend webpage

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have created a custom post type "Events" and added the categories function for it.  However, the categories only shows in the backend CMS which I can set and add new categories, but no message indicating the category that a event was set for in the front end webpage.

How can I make the events categories information shown in the front end webpage?

I have copied the code below:

```
function enable_event_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'events',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Events' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Event' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Event' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New Event' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Event' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Event' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No events found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No events found in trash' )
            ),
            'public' => true,

                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments'),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "events"), // Permalinks format
            'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/date.png',  // Icon Path
            'menu_position' => '5'
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'enable_event_posttype' );



add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
  register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'events', array( 'hierarchical' => true,  'label' => 'Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you got a permalink conflict. You can't give two "things" the same slug/URi in WordPress. Please try it with a different slug than `events` either for the custom post type or the custom taxonomy.

<sub>*And yes, I know, this answer will be flagged as "low quality" due to its length.*</sub>